# Jenkins: "Could not initialize class org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist"

Tags: jenkins

(At lease) one of my Jenkins CI-jobs suddenly stopped working. Seems like the Jenkins runtime can't find one of its expected classes. Have anyone seen this error before, and know what may be causing it? I'm running version 2.212 on Debian. The Script Security Plugin is running version 1.68.

```
Started by user John Doe
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git ssh://git@git.acme.com:7999/my/repo.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:183)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:189)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:193)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:100)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:405)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:281)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

UPDATE: I downgraded Script Security Plugin to version 1.67, and now the job works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do have a lot of similar error messages since the update to 2.212 and script security plugin 1.68. Downgrading the latter to 1.67 solved my issues for now.

Comment: Downgrading script security to 1.67 with Jenkins 2.212 still doesn't work. Just tested - same error.

Comment: Have you restarted your instance?

Comment: Yes, several times.  I did update all libs when I first noticed the problem, and restarted but no fix.  Then I read this posting and tried downgrading Script Security, restarted again and no fix.

Comment: Try to upgrade to the new Jenkins version 2.213 - this should help.

Comment: Upgrading to Bugfix version 2.213 solved this issue for me. Running now again with 1.68 Plugin

Answer (score 8):

**Update**:

An upgrade to **[Jenkins Version 2.213](https://jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.213)** fixes the issue.

> Fix plugin class resource loading failures for plugins which include
> library JARs. At least the script-security and active-directory
> plugins are known to be affected. (regression in 2.112) (issue 60641,
> issue 60644)

---

**Original answer:**

It is a known issue ([JENKINS-60644](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60644) and [JENKINS-60641](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60641)) with Script Security Plugin 1.68 and Jenkins 2.212.

It is adviced to downgrade to [Jenkins 2.211](https://jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.212).

> WARNING: This release [2.212] introduces a critical regression, see
> JENKINS-60644. Please avoid updating to this version.

Comment: I checked https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/ but didn't find 2.211.  Any ideas where I should be looking?

Comment: Rather upgrade it to the new version 2.213 which fixes the issue as well.

Comment: upgrading to 2.213 worked here to this morning as well

Answer (score 3):

V2.212 has regression and causing the described bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60644
New version will be published soon fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to V2.213 and the issue was resolved for me.